# Query to perform date arithmetic on same field depending upon separate status field?

Tags: oracle11g

I have an Oracle table that contains data similar to the following:

```
ID | STATUS |      TIME
-------------------------------
 1 |   IN   |  2013/26/03 00:00
 1 |   OUT  |  2013/26/03 07:00
 1 |   IN   |  2013/27/03 03:00
 2 |   IN   |  2013/26/03 01:00
 2 |   OUT  |  2013/26/03 06:00
 3 |   IN   |  2013/26/03 01:30
        .
        .
```

The STATUS represents check-in and check-out, where the ID represents individuals.

I've come up with a query using sub-queries but it seems inelegant and inefficient.  Is it possible to write a single query (meaning no sub-queries) to calculate an elapsed time (IN -> OUT) for each ID?

UPDATE: Also, would it be possible to display the elapsed time the individual is OUT?  For example in the data listed above Individual #1 is IN for 7 hours, but OUT for 20 hours (2013/27/03 03:00 - 2013/26/03 07:00).  Since this would be calculated across records I'm not sure how this can be written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
select timein.id, 24 * (timeout.time - timein.time) ElapsedTime
from t timein 
left outer join t timeout on timein.id = timeout.id
where timein.status = 'IN' and timeout.status = 'OUT'
```

if your time field is char datatype then you need to do this

```
select timein.id, 24 * (TO_DATE(timeout.time, 'YYYY-DD-MM hh24:mi') 
                      - TO_DATE(timein.time, 'YYYY-DD-MM hh24:mi')) ElapsedTime
from t timein 
left outer join t timeout on timein.id = timeout.id
where timein.status = 'IN' and timeout.status = 'OUT'
```

try this for days with time

```
select timein.id, NUMTODSINTERVAL((timeout.time - timein.time),'day') ElapsedTime
from t timein 
left outer join t timeout on timein.id = timeout.id
where timein.status = 'IN' and timeout.status = 'OUT'
```

For In and Out time you can use this and modify according to your data

```
with cte as
(
select t.id, status,
24 * (t.time - LAG(t.time) 
  OVER (partition by id ORDER BY t.time)) AS diff
from t
)
select t1.id, t1.diff timeIn, t2.diff timeOut
from cte t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
cte t2 on t1.id = t2.id  and t2.status = 'IN' and t2.diff is not null
where t1.status = 'OUT'
```

Comment: Perfect and quickly answered.  I greatly enjoy these opportunities to learn a new technique.  I always forget about naming the join.  Thanks!

Comment: If this is too far outside the scope of the original question let me know, but would it be possible to also calculate the total time OUT as well?  Would this require an additional query?

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant was if we compare the out time from one record to the in time of the next record, can we say how long the individual was out?

Comment: @McArthey, i'm not understanding your question, can you explain with example values?

Comment: @McArthey, check updated answer, you can use that and modify it to make it work to what you want